# How to reduce the line spacing on the main title?

Tags: r, shiny

I have this header section on my app. I would like to reduce the spacing on the `HTML` title to make it more compact and vertically centered.

```
dashboardPage( dashboardHeader( 
                   title = HTML("Consulta de esquemas de vacunacion"), 
                   titleWidth = 320,
                   
                   tags$li(a(href = '.',
                             img(src = 'logo-s.png',
                                 title = "Reiniciar app", height = "80px"),
                             style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"),
                           class = "dropdown"),
                   
                   tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                           tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 80px; }"),
                           tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 100px;}"),
                           tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 80px; padding-top: 40px !important;}"),
                           tags$style(".navbar {min-height:80px !important}")
                   )            
                   
                   )
                   .... )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
dashboardPage( dashboardHeader(
  title = h2("Consulta de esquemas de vacunacion", 
              style="vertical-align:center; font-size:25px; font-family: monospace;"), 
  titleWidth = 320,....
```

[image: output]

Comment: Looks like a nice approach but Im having issues with the website title after this change. https://i.imgur.com/CURzKFk.jpeg

Comment: Try to wrap in a `div` as  `title = div(h2(...))`

Comment: no luck so far. title is still messed up